# Why isn't subprocess.Popen starting an app correctly from a .pyw file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a .pyw python program that I use to give myself some keyboard shortcuts at work. One of the shortcuts is to open a new Google page. However, every time I try to use this shortcut it will open a blank white window for about 2 seconds, then the window closes. No new google page is opened, and no errors are given. This is also the case for all the other apps I try to open. This code does seem to work if it's in a .py file, however I would prefer if I could get it to work in my .pyw file.

Here is the code I am using:

```
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, DEVNULL

Popen([r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'], stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT
```

I am using Python 3.10 on Windows 10.

Comment: Why are you not using the existing `subprocess.DEVNULL`? Of course it can't print any errors when you redirect them to `/dev/null`.

Comment: @tripleee I'm still pretty new to this, so this is partially code I've taken from some examples I've seen. However, this does work, but only for .py files for some reason. I will update my question.

Comment: Works fine on my windows system.